# Is it possible to hide a custom field type plugin from the popup tab when double clicking an entry?

Tags: plugin-development

Is it possible to hide a custom field from the modal that appears when you double-click on a related entry inside a Entries field?

In other words, I don't want my custom field to be visible within the modal that comes from getEditorHtml.

===== Updated based on accepted answer below =====

Based on the accepted answer from @Tyler Willingham I used the following code in my plugin's main plugin file:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    if (craft()->request->isCpRequest()) {
        craft()->templates->includeJsResource('myPlugin/js/myJs.js');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a setting you can apply to the plugin that corresponds to your custom field, it doesn't look like such a setting exists.

**Update:** I was just made aware of this [Craft CP JS plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs/) in another question. It looks like you could potentially hide your plugin from displaying. It's not as elegant as a first-party solution but it may be worth a shot

Comment: Opinion: I could see it being useful to have a way to toggle which fields are available for quick edits (maybe only required fields?).

Comment: I agree that this feature would be useful, but as in my case, I don't want it to be optional. I would love for a way for the plugin to the force this behavior anytime the Field Type is being used.

Comment: Can you provide some context for when this doesn't make sense? Does the visual representation of your field not make sense within the confines of the modal?

Comment: Pretty much. I have a plugin that opens up a modal for it's management and you'd start getting modals in modals, and it could cascade.

Comment: Seems like a good use case for such a setting. I'm convinced :)

Comment: I was just made aware of [this Craft CP JS plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs/) plugin in another question. It looks like you could potentially hide your plugin from displaying. It's not as elegant as a first-party solution but it may be worth a shot.

Comment: I was able to use this method to get this to work! It's definitely a bit hacky but it works. Do you want to break this comment out into an answer or edit this answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Great! I just updated my answer. Thank you